# Spring Integration - JMS outbound adapter post-send database update

Tags: spring-integration

We previously used to have a Spring Integration flow (XML configuration-based) where we would do an update in a database after sending a message to a JMS queue. To achieve this, the SI flow was configured with a publish-subscribe queue channel as an input to a JMS Outbound Channel Adapter (order 0) and a Service Activator (order 1). The idea here being that after a successful JMS send, the service activator would be called thus, updating the data in the database.

We are now in the process of updating our flows to work with `spring-integration:4.0.x` APIs and wanted to use this opportunity to see if the described flow pattern is still a good/recommended way of doing a database update after a successful JMS send or if there is now a simpler/better way of achieving this? As a side note, our flows are now being implemented using `spring-integration-java-dsl:1.0.0.M3` APIs.

Thanks in advance for any input on this,

PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> publish-subscribe queue channel

There's no such thing as a pub-sub **queue** channel; by definition, it's a **subscribable** channel; so I assume that's what you mean.

It is one of the ways to do what you need, and perfectly fine; you can also achieve the same result with a `RecipientListRouter`. The dsl syntax is quite nice, especially with Java 8; see the [SpringOne demo app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/dsl/si4demo/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/si4demo/springone/f/FMail.java#L70) for an example.

Comment: Hi Gary, you are right. I am not sure where the **queue** bit came from! The channel class I am using for this is `org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel` and it is working fine. We are using dsl and Java 8 however, so will take a look at the `RecipientListRouter` as you mentioned and see how that compares. Thanks!